# Show only the MIN/MAX value on Y-AXIS with C3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3

I would like to have the y-axis only with the min/max values of my data.
I tried to use the d3 directive but without results.

I had a look at google but I didn't find an answer to achieve this behaviour.

Below the code:

```
 $.getJSON('assets/json/chartc3.json', function(data) 
{ 

    scene=data;
    var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chartc3',
    data: 
        {

            json: scene,
            keys: 
            {
                    x: 'round',
                    value: ['Marketable', 'Total Requested Capacity', 'Your Bid'],
            },
            types: {
                Marketable: 'area'
            },
            colors: {
                Marketable: '#A09FA2',
                'Total Requested Capacity': '#272E80',
                'Your Bid': '#8EBF60'
            }
        },
    axis: 
    {
        x: {
            tick: 
            {
                culling: 
                {
                    max: 10
                }
            },
          type: 'category'
        },
        y: 
        {

            min: 0,
             padding : {
              bottom : 0
            },
            tick: 
            {
                values: [[0], [***d3.max(scene)]***],

                format:  function (d) { return d3.format(',f')(d) +' kWh/h' }
      //or format: function (d) { return '$' + d; }
            }
        }
      }.........
```

How could I achieve the result described above ? d3.max(scene) returns NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is scene is not an array its a json object.

```
var k = d3.max([1,5,2])
k will be 5
```

so you will need to pass an array of elements which constitute your y ordinals.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
d3.max(arr, function(d){return numberic value});
```

or

```
var arr = scene.map(function(d){return ...the number value..})
y:{
    min:d3.min(arr),
    max:d3.max(arr)
},
```

the function depends on the array element of your data.

Comment: My json file contains the different series that I need to draw... so I should to have a loop for every series and return the number ? I never used this function.

Answer (score 0):

I used a little function to calculate the max by myself.

```
var maxs=0;
    for (var j=0; j<scene.length; j++) {
        var maxtemp=Math.max(scene[j].Marketable, scene[j]['Your Bid'], scene[j]['Total Requested Capacity']);
        maxs=Math.max(maxs, maxtemp);
    }
```